# How do I reduce my TFS-Admin privileges when I work as a developer?

Tags: tfs, admin

I've got admin privileges for TFS, but I also work as a developer in projects that I look after. In Linux-Land, I'd be a normal user and I'd switch to root when I needed to do some admin, how could I do the same re:TFS? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a second user who has admin rights, and give your own user normal (contributor) rights.
Then, you will run vs normally to use it as a developer, and run as TFS admin for administrative actions.
To do that, open command line, and use the runas command with the /netonly argument, sending the tfs admin credentials.

Comment: basically you're saying I need to get "another (admin) me" added to the domain? I was trying to avoid that if possible

Comment: You can't have two different sets of permissions for the same user. Even in Linux, when you elevate your permissions, you're actually going in as the user named 'root'.